# How do I safely convert an MD5 hash into buckets in Java/Scala?

Tags: java, scala, hash, md5

I would like to hash IDs into buckets such that

1. There is no bias towards a particular bucket
2. The same ID should always be assigned to the same bucket
3. IDs should be distributed across all buckets independently
4. Buckets should be (almost) equal in size

My strategy is to get an MD5 hash of the ID, convert it into a number and then mod it into a bucket.

```
val hash: Array[Byte] = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5").digest("Hello")
val number: java.math.BigInteger = new BigInteger(hash)
val bucket = number.mod(new BigInteger("1000"))
```

Does this approach maintain the nice properties that MD5 provides? Would this achieve the goals above?

Comment: what's wrong with hashCode()? Its goals are the same as yours, and unless your IDs have a bizarre pattern that causes a bad distribution, it should be sufficient. And muuuuuch faster than using MD5.

Comment: What type is your `ID`? int? Something else?

Comment: I have no real control over the ID type. The system leaves IDs configurable, and they will most likely be longs or Strings.

Comment: @JBNizet The particular application I am working on very likely needs MD5 because it is very sensitive to the bucketing/randomization algorithm. The question is more about the best way of getting from MD5 to (Integer) buckets.

Comment: `Arrays.hashCode(digestBytes)`

Comment: That's not Java. Also: what nice properties are you thinking of? md5 is a very slow hash function if you don't care about cryptographic security, and generally considered broken if you do.

Comment: Consider a type that is configured that has a broken `hashCode()` method or one that doesn't meet your requirements. Do you need a `HashMap` or similar collection that uses _your_ implementation instead?

Comment: @AlanStokes I am writing this in Scala, so by saying Java/Scala, I mean that a solution in either language would work for me.

Comment: @jdphenix The input comes in as a String or Long or, more generally, an byte array. I am not using this for lookups (HashMap). The bucketing is the input to more complicated steps further in the data flow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is sound (if slow), and maintains all the good properties of MD5 except collision resistance.

A lack of collision resistance is rarely a concern in a bucket selection algorithm though. Exploitation requires the system 1. to bucket millions of IDs provided by an untrusted party and 2. to depend on roughly uniform distribution for reliability and/or correctness.